# Admin login and upload security

Tags: php, html

I have a comics site which I'd like to easy my uploading of image paths to the database.

I have a login screen which checks as such for correct credentials:

```
            <?php 

        $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : "";
        $password = isset($_POST['pw']) ? $_POST['pw'] : "";


        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            if(verify($username, $password) == 1) {
                header("Location: ?action=admin");
            }
            else {
                echo "<center>Incorrect credentials</center>";
            }
        }

        function verify($user, $pw) {
            include './scripts/dbconnect.php';

            $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='" . $user . "' AND password='" . $pw . "'"); 

            return $result->num_rows;
        }

        include 'include/footer.php';
        ?>
```

Which will then log them in to the upload screen.

Unfortunately, all the user has to do is guess what my url might be for the upload page and they can skip my login screen...

/HTwS/?action=login (just replace 'login' with 'admin' and you're there...) So, my first line of defense will be to not make my upload page name so obvious... but what happens if a user still guesses it... can I verify in another way which won't let them just change the url up?

Thanks!

Comment: the usual way to do that is to have the login procedure create a session variable that, if not set, will cause the user to be redirected to the login page.

Comment: It's great that you're using mysqli. But you're still vulnerable to injections because you're just dumping the input right into it.

Comment: You might as well just use `.htauth`, unless you have a dozen admins. Yes, and http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @maro is that the same thing as .htaccess? I might recommend using password protected area using .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is pretty insecure. What you're going to want to do is set some session variables when you login (`$_SESSION[user_id]`, `$_SESSION[permission_type]`, etc...). You can then have a function such as `verifyAdmin()` at the top of each admin page that would check if the logged in user is in fact an admin by checking the `$_SESSION` variables you just set. If they're not, they get redirected to the login page.

When the admin logs in, set some session variables as such:

```
$_SESSION[user_id] = id_of_admin;
$_SESSION[permission_type] = 'admin';
```

verifyAdmin would look something like this:

```
function verifyAdmin() {
   if(!isset($_SESSION[username]) || !isset($_SESSION[permission_type]) || $_SESSION[permission_type] != 'admin'){
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
}
```

Then on the top of each admin page you can simply do this:

`verifyAdmin();`

Your verify function should look like this:

```
function verify($user, $pw) {
    include './scripts/dbconnect.php';
    $result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='" . $user . "' AND password='" . $pw . "'");
    if ($result -> num_rows == 1) {
        $_SESSION[username] = $user;
        $_SESSION[permission_type] = 'admin';
    }
    return $result -> num_rows;
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing that, but wasn't really getting the hang of using the sessions. Can you provide a brief example given my code as to how you'd integrate a session check?

Comment: okay cool. My breakdown in understanding is this: I understand where other superglobals get their values from, like $_POST (which gets its value from a form submission) or $_GET (which gets its value from the URL), but where is $_SESSION getting its value from? Where the 'user_id' in $_SESSION['user_id'] coming from? I checked http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php for the answer, but it still wasn't clear.

Comment: Check my update to your function. You don't need to user user_id it was just a suggestion. You can use username. Just something to validate.

Comment: Okay, so a $_SESSION variable will automatically generate a unique ID and store user-chosen variables based on that Unique ID?

Comment: A session variable will store data you tell it to store for the time a session is active. `$_SESSION[name_of_session_variable] = value_of_session_variable`. You can call this variable any time and anywhere you've started your session.

Comment: Sean, you've given both Session variables their values from within verify($user, $pw)... but I don't think function verifyAdmin() has access to those... is there some way I can make those sessions global so verifyAdmin() has access to them?

Comment: Btw, I have my html login form code in the same file as the php login code~ so how can I call the verifyAdmin() function in any admin page without including the whole login.php file (because then the html form will show up again)

Answer (score 0):

This chunk of code is also vulnerable to SQL injection. You need to sanitize those $_POST variables.